# Python multiple dataframe to one file

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 datafram like shown below, i need to write it to csv file one by one , if possable to add headers after each dataframe

df1 :

```
            Source      0
  Carrefour_App-BH   6193
        Talabat-BH   5403
Luluhypermarket-BH  12024
```

df2:

```
            Source  Overlap Products  Competitor Exclusive  Talabat Exclusive
  Carrefour_App-BH              1044                5149.0                NaN
Luluhypermarket-BH              1343               10681.0                NaN
        Talabat-BH              3196                   NaN             2207.0
```

required output in csv file

```
Total count
            Source    0
  Carrefour_App-BH    6193
        Talabat-BH    5403
Luluhypermarket-BH    12024

category count

            Source  Overlap Products  Competitor Exclusive  Talabat Exclusive
  Carrefour_App-BH              1044                5149.0                NaN
Luluhypermarket-BH              1343               10681.0                NaN
        Talabat-BH              3196                   NaN             2207.0
```

Code i have tried :

```
total_source_count_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(total_source_count,orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Source'})
total_overlap_count_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(total_overlap_count,orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Source'})
final_df = pd.concat([total_source_count_df, total_overlap_count_df,], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this, maybe helps you:

```py
import pandas as pd
  
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Source': {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"},
                   'Total': {0: 80, 1: 77, 2: 54}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Source': {0: "a", 1: "b", 2: "c"},
                   'Value1': {0: 10, 1: 11, 2: 16},
                   'Value2': {0: 27, 1: 23, 2: 21},
                   'Value3': {0: 43, 1: 33, 2: 17}})

final_df = df1.merge(df2, on='Source', how='left')

final_df.to_csv("final_df.csv", sep='\t')
```

output:

[image]